Why is my Custom date class not serialisable
I have the following custom date class in my current Android application
import kotlinx.datetime.LocalDate
import kotlinx.datetime.format
import kotlinx.serialization.Serializable
import shared.dates.MyDateFormatterFactory.createFormatter
import kotlin.properties.Delegates

@Serializable
data class MyDate internal constructor(
    val format: String,
    internal var date: LocalDate
) {
    val string get() = _stringRepresentation
    private val formatter = createFormatter(format)

    private var _stringRepresentation by Delegates.observable(date.format(formatter)) { _, _, newValue ->
        date = LocalDate.parse(newValue, formatter)
    }

    internal var internalDate by Delegates.observable(date) { _, oldValue, newValue ->
        if (newValue != oldValue) {
            date = newValue
            _stringRepresentation = date.format(formatter)
        }
    }

    fun set(newDate: String) {
        _stringRepresentation = newDate
    }

    override fun toString() = _stringRepresentation
}

when I attempt to pass it as args to an Activity i get the following runtime exception
FATAL EXCEPTION: main (Ask Gemini)
Process: com.squareup.timessquare.sample, PID: 27037
java.lang.RuntimeException: Parcelable encountered IOException writing serializable object (name = organisation.research.daily.FrankArgs)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:2126)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeValue(Parcel.java:1896)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeArrayMapInternal(Parcel.java:988)
    at android.os.BaseBundle.writeToParcelInner(BaseBundle.java:1620)
    at android.os.Bundle.writeToParcel(Bundle.java:1303)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeBundle(Parcel.java:1057)
    at android.content.Intent.writeToParcel(Intent.java:11512)
    at android.app.IActivityTaskManager$Stub$Proxy.startActivity(IActivityTaskManager.java:4248)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1723)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5377)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.kt:704)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:5335)
    at androidx.activity.ComponentActivity.startActivityForResult(ComponentActivity.kt:683)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5721)
    at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:5674)
    at organisation.uikit.core.extensions.IntentExtensionsKt.startActivity(IntentExtensions.kt:16)
    at organisation.research.daily.AFrank$Companion.invoke(AFrank.kt:1148)
    at organisation.research.module.routing.ModuleRunner.startFrankProject$lambda$5(ModuleRunner.kt:140)
    at organisation.research.module.routing.ModuleRunner.$r8$lambda$TpjcOuyCuzL1feKmvclHTm30cjY(Unknown Source:0)
    at organisation.research.module.routing.ModuleRunner$$ExternalSyntheticLambda5.invoke(D8$$SyntheticClass:0)
    at organisation.research.module.routing.ModuleRunner$preventModuleMissingAreFile$1.invokeSuspend(ModuleRunner.kt:358)
    at kotlin.coroutines.jvm.internal.BaseContinuationImpl.resumeWith(ContinuationImpl.kt:33)
    at kotlinx.coroutines.DispatchedTask.run(DispatchedTask.kt:104)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:246)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8653)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:602)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1130)
    Suppressed: kotlinx.coroutines.internal.DiagnosticCoroutineContextException: [StandaloneCoroutine{Cancelling}@9473510, Dispatchers.Main]
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: shared.dates.MyDate
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1240)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.defaultWriteFields(ObjectOutputStream.java:1604)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeSerialData(ObjectOutputStream.java:1565)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeOrdinaryObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:1488)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject0(ObjectOutputStream.java:1234)
    at java.io.ObjectOutputStream.writeObject(ObjectOutputStream.java:354)
    at android.os.Parcel.writeSerializable(Parcel.java:2121)
    ... 29 more

what is the issue? MyDate has to vals one is String the other kotlinx.datetime.LocalDate which are both serialisable in their own right.
why is MyDate data class not serialisable?
is the issue caused by the two by Delegates.observable?
As when I replace @Serializable with implenting java.io.Serializable i get the following exception
Caused by: java.io.NotSerializableException: shared.dates.MyDate$special$$inlined$observable$1


What type is this "private val formatter = createFormatter(format)"? Is that property serializable?

@DavidWasser is of type kotlinx.datetime.format.DateTimeFormat, which is public sealed interface DateTimeFormat, which i create using this DSL LocalDate.Format {}

So the DateTimeFormat is probably not serializable

It looks like every property in this class except the constructor properties might not be serializable.

may be you can try this
@Parcelize
@Serializable
data class MyDate internal constructor(
    val format: String,
    internal var date: LocalDate
) : Parcelable {
    // Your existing properties and methods remain the same.
}


ive already tried this and it did work
